# Unit testing angular mat-form

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, karma-jasmine

I am new at Angular Testing.

I want to test all the scenarios with a form (valid form, required form, etc)

That's my html:

```
<div class="content" *ngIf="!recordsFound">
  <div class="alert">
    <span>OOOPS! No recordings found. You can add a new one:</span>
  </div>
  <form [formGroup]="recordingForm" #formDirective="ngForm" id="recordingForm">
    <div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Artist*</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Artist" formControlName="artist" />
          <mat-error>Required input</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Title*</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Title" formControlName="title" />
          <mat-error>Required input</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>ISRC</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="ISRC" formControlName="isrc" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <div>
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Duration</mat-label>
          <input matInput placeholder="Duration" formControlName="duration" />
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
      <button mat-stroked-button color="primary" (click)="save()" [disabled]="!recordingForm.valid">
        Add recording <mat-icon>music_note</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Example, test check if form is valid and fields required are not empty:

```
  it ('check if form is valid and required fields not empty',() =>{
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddRecordingComponent);
    const formArtistElement: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#recordingForm').querySelectorAll('input')[0];
    const formTitleElement: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#recordingForm').querySelectorAll('input')[1];
    formArtistElement.value='Rihanna';
    formTitleElement.value='Umbrella';
    formArtistElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    formTitleElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
    const isFormValid = fixture.componentInstance.recordingForm.valid;
    
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(isFormValid).toBeTruthy();
    })
  
  });
```

I am getting this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelectorAll' of null`
How I can access to the form through the spec file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Please try this

```
it ('check if form is valid and required fields not empty',() =>{
    const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AddRecordingComponent);
    let component = fixture.componentInstance;
    component.recordsFound = false; // To make form visible
    fixture.detectChanges();
    const formArtistElement: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#recordingForm')?.querySelectorAll('input')[0];
    const formTitleElement: HTMLInputElement = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#recordingForm')?.querySelectorAll('input')[1];
    if(formArtistElement) {
      formArtistElement.value='Rihanna';
      formTitleElement.value='Umbrella';
      formArtistElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      formTitleElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
      const isFormValid = fixture.componentInstance.recordingForm.valid;
    }
    
    fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
      expect(isFormValid).toBeTruthy();
    })
  
  });
```

Comment: I get this error: AddRecordingComponent > check if form is valid
Error: NG0301: Export of name 'ngForm' not found!. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0301